# How to change a textview with both addTextChangedListener and RadioButton changes

Tags: android, textview, radio-button

I have a textview that I have linked to an edittext box so that when it is edited, it changes my textview. I have a radiobutton used in the interpretation of the textview but it has to be selected before i edit the edittext box in question.

What I would like is for the textview to be changed when i change the radiobutton AS WELL AS when i change the edittext boxes. An example is:

I have 3 Edittext boxes and 1 RadioGroup (consisting of 2 RadioButtons [but one of the buttons is selected by default]). I have 1 Textview.
I would like it so that when all edittext boxes are filled in, the textview is changed. I also want it so that when i change the radiobutton, it will change the textview again. And then i can go back and edit any of the 3 edittext boxes and it will change the textview. At the moment, i only have 1 addTextChangedListener in use at the moment, which is on the edditext box at the bottom of the screen (in the hope the user fills all the top fields in first). But the problem is that if the user changes the topmost edittext box, it doesnt change the textview because the listener is on the bottom box.

Hope that is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a text changed listener to *all* the text boxes.

This listener should be the same for all of them. It simply needs to check if the other boxes have been filled.

```
if(
  textBox1.getText().toString() != "" &&
  textBox2.getText().toString() != "" &&
  textBox3.getText().toString() != "") {
    //All boxes have a value, so change the TextView
    ....
}
```